# how to identify a multisite installation

Tags: multisite

I am creating a plugin.

I want to add a different options page, based on multisite or single site.

I need a code which can identify installation is Multisite or single site.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious choice would be the [**`is_multisite()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite) conditional template tag.

Used as such:

```
if ( is_multisite() ) {
    // Multisite is enabled;
    // do something
}
```